# Overcome doze in android for audio streaming

Tags: android, doze

I am pretty new to android development. I am currently working for our company android app which is a real-time(low latency) audio receiver. The app works fine so far. But for Android versions >= Marshmallow because of the doze effect the network gets disconnected and the streaming stops. I went through several forums and used the "intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);" setting to disable battery optimizations. Also we display a in-app dialog box to intimate the user that the app is not battery optimized and they change it in the settings options.
Is this sufficient for Google(https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases) ? Because in some forums i read google suspends apps if they disable battery optimizations.
Please give your inputs.

Comment: "Is this sufficient for Google" how are we supposed to answer, we are not google

Comment: Just asking of your experience to this problem ? As i also mentioned i am a newbie to android developement. Could you just suggest any google support mail or forum where I can also query ??